# Parse line of text and match with parse of CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

As a continuation of a script I'm running, working on the following.

I have a CSV file that has formatted information, example as follows:

File named `Import.csv`:

```
Name,email,x,y,z
\I\RS\T\Name1\c\x,email@jksjks,d,f
\I\RS\T\Name2\d\f,email@jsshjs,d,f
...
```

This file is large.

I also have another file called `Note.txt`.

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
...
```

I'm trying to get the content of `Import.csv` and for each line in `Note.txt` if the line in `Note.txt` matches any line in `Import.csv`, then copy that line into a CSV with append. Continue adding every other line that is matched.  Then this loops on each line of the CSV.

I need to find the best way to do it without having it import the CSV multiple times, since it is large.

What I got does the opposite though, I think:

```cs
$Dir = PathToFile
$import = Import-Csv $Dir\import.csv
$NoteFile = "$Dir\Note.txt"
$Note = GC $NoteFile
$Name = (($Import.Name).Split("\"))[4]

foreach ($j in $import) {
  foreach ($i in $Note) {
    $j | where {$Name -eq "$i"} | Export-Csv "$Dir\Result.csv" -NoTypeInfo -Append
  }
}
```

This takes too long and I'm not getting the extraction I need.

Comment: You're only assigning `$name` once, that's probably your problem

Comment: `$name = (gc note.txt) -join '|'; ipcsv import.csv |? Name -match $name | epcsv result.csv -NoType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This takes too long and I'm not getting the extraction I need.

That's because you only assign `$name` once, outside of the outer `foreach` loop, so you're basically performing the same X comparisons for each line in the CSV.

I would rewrite the nested loops as a single `Where-Object` filter, using the `-contains` operator:

```
$Import |Where-Object {$Note -contains $_.Name.Split('\')[4]} |Export-Csv "$Dir\Result.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: That's simpler than my approach. I first thought that he'd wanted the output in different files, so I grouped the rows. Howerver, if all output goes into the same file anyway, separating it first is rather pointless. %|

Comment: Thanks this worked flawlessly and not time consume at all.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen  - This worked flawless.  Question, If I needed to log any lines of the Note file that weren't found in the CSV, how would I go about that?  I tried importing the resultant filtered csv and sort of reversed the where-object but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @acastrellon23 I'd do that separately, (before or after exporting, depending of the size of the data set), but since this is a separate question I'd say [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (feel free to reference this one)

Answer (score 1):

Group the imported data by your distinguishing feature, filter the groups by name, then expand the remaining groups and write the data to the output file:

```cs
Import-Csv "$Dir\import.csv" |
  Group-Object { $_.Name.Split('\')[4] } |
  Where-Object { $Note -contains $_.Name } |
  Select-Object -Expand Group |
  Export-Csv "$Dir\Result.csv" -NoType
```